# qt post and get request

Tags: qt, post, get

I'm trying to log in to a webpage and then download some data that only members can download.

I've performed the *post* request and then the *get* request, for some reason the *get* request was finished first.

Is there any way to wait for the *post* to be finished or make it done first?

edit:

```
void downloader::LoginToHost()
{
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://www.example.com/login.php"));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

    QByteArray data("email=example&password=");
    manager->post(request,data);
}

void  downloader::Do_Request(QUrl url)
{
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void downloader::finished(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    QMessageBox mess;

    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        std::ofstream source("source-code.txt");
        QString content = reply->readAll();
        source << content.toStdString() << std::endl;
        source.close();

        mess.setText("Done download!");
    }
    else mess.setText(reply->errorString());

    mess.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the post and don't send the get until the post returns and triggers the [finished](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#finished) signal in QNetworkReply.

Assuming there are two requests, one for the post and one for the get, which you've set up, here's an outline of what you can do: -

```
QNetworkRequst postRequest;
QNetworkRequest getRequest;
```

Sending the postRequest returns a QNetworkReply...

```
QNetworkAccessManager* networkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager;

QNetworkReply postReply = networkAccessManager->post(postRequest, someData);
QNetworkReply getReply = nullptr; // C++ 11 nullptr
```

You can then connect to the postReply finished signal: -

```
// using a connection to a lambda function, send the get request when post has finished
connect(postReply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [this, networkAccessManager, getRequest, getReply](){

    // handle the reply...
    ...
    // send the getRequest
    getReply = networkAccessManager->get(getRequest);

});
```

Comment: How can I do that? How can I distinguish between the requests in the finished signal? Sorry, but I'm new at this.